# Retopologizing -- Is it bad practice to knife a face in order to make enough edges to bridge edge loops?

Tags: edges

Let's say you want to connect two pieces of your topology using "bridge edge loops" but you have 2 edges on one side and 1 edge on the other.

I'm tempted to use the knife to split a face, so that the edges are 2 and 2.

The course I'm taking seems to encourage splitting all the faces leading up to that edge too, using loop cut & slide.

Is it bad practice to split just a single face to connect edges? (...even if it doesn't mess up the "edge flow"?)

Pic attached, if it helps.

[image: hope this is clear]

Comment: The knife cut is great for [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AQRk.png).

Comment: Looking at the topology I would use an edge loop. You can split with a knife and create an ngon but could cause issues down the line

Comment: If you have an image that shows more clearly what you are modeling, I could suggest some way to achieve a lup that eliminates the Ngons and works better for you.